# Get the output from python tests in ruby script

Tags: python, ruby

I have a Python project with some tests in different folders and files. I wanted to write a script which executes all tests for the project and outputs some results. I want it to be a ruby script (because I know Ruby more than Python and for now I enjoy it more) and I was thinking to get the output from the tests and to parse them with ruby and to output something like "48 tests run in total, all ok" instead of the the output from python.

Long story short - I want I way to get the output from `python test_something.py` in a variable or in a file and I want nothing from it on the screen.

Here are my tries:

```
tests = Dir.glob("**/test_*")
wd = Dir.pwd

output = ''
tests.each do |test|
  Dir.chdir(File.dirname(test))
  # output += `python #{File.basename(test)}`
  # system("python #{File.basename(test)} >> f.txt")
  Dir.chdir(wd)
end
```

I tried both things which are commented, but both of them print the result on the standard exit and in the first one output variable is empty, in the second one the file is created but is empty again :(

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test framework might have send the result to `STDERR`. Try use `Open3.capture3` to capture the standard error.

```
require 'open3'

...

stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(%{python "#{File.basename(test)}"})
```

and write the standard output and standard error to the destination:

```
File.write("f.txt", stdout + stderr)
```

You may check `status.success?` to see if you write the external command right. However, the test framework may return non-zero exit code on failed tests. In that case, you should check the `stderr` to see the actual error output.

Comment: @Faery glad to see it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use [Open3.capture2](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2) as below:

```
output, _ = Open3.capture2("python #{File.basename(test)")
```

To write output to a file do as below:

```
File.write("f.txt", output)
```

Comment: It's the same again :( output variable is empty each time, so the file is empty, too and I see the result on the standart exit :( I execute this with `ruby name_of_file.rb`

Comment: `Open3.capture2` captures standard output, which is the same as the back quote. If @Faery cannot capture anything with back quote, `Open.capture2` won't work either.

Comment: @ArieShaw it is not the same as backticks as it returns a `Process::Status` object which backticks doesn't, the difference between this and your answer is that you are capturing `stderr`

Comment: @bjhaid You threw status away.